# RegEx how I can find these 3 groups?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with three different texts inside the exact line, separated by a `_`

I want a regex to extract the first part of the data, a regex for the second, and one for the last part.

The string is like `xxxxxx_yyyyyyy_zzzzzz` (where x, y, and z it's random data).

I have tried this:

```
^[^_]*
```

But I can only figure out how to match the first part of the data for x.

Comment: You got a good start. How could you use that for the rest of the string? I mean, right now you match everything that is not a `_`. What comes next? A `_`, again everything that is ***not*** a `_`, another `_` and again anything but it. I'm sure that with a bit more time you would get to it...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Do you mean like this? ^[^_]*_^[^_]*

Comment: It's hard to read without code-formating. You do that by using back-ticks (\`). I encourage you to use regex101.com to test your regex

Comment: Just drop the `^` start anchor [like this?](https://regex101.com/r/abd6Fp/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given us what programming language you are using regex from.  But, generally, this is what you want:

```
^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$
```

The parenthesis are "capturing groups" which can then be referred to as `\x`, `$x`, some other way where x is 1, 2 or 3.  That depends on your regex implementation and programming language.  Using your example string, `\2` would be `yyyyyyy`.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help @Cargo23, that seems to be what I'm looking for. But using the expression: ^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$ it returns the three groups in the same "result".
I'm looking for an expression to just extract and only xxxx, one for yyyy and one for zzzz

PD: JavaScript Regex

Comment: Check out this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, you can use positive look-ahead `(?=)` and positive look-behind `(?<=)` capture groups like this:

```
(?<=_|^)\d+(?=$|_)
```

This is relatively safe `RegExp`, as long as original string only contain numbers.

Explanation and examples: https://regex101.com/r/ZptWHV/1